# Cocoalibspotify, how to trigger an action when playlist plays the next track

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I have a playlist, and I want to sequentially play through the tracks, but every time a new track is loaded, I want to call a function. How would I go about listening for this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SPPlaybackManager`, the playback class in CocoaLibSpotify, doesn't automatically play tracks sequentially, so you have to manually tell it to play each time. Since you're managing that, you already know when a new track is starting playback.

Additionally, `SPPlaybackManagerDelegate` has a method `-playbackManagerWillStartPlayingAudio:`, which will let you know when audio starts hitting the speakers.